# Main water valve leaking

Tags: plumbing, leak, valve

I had a leaky fitting (on the left side) so I replaced it, but now my main valve has a slow leak through the handle (right side)

I've tried securing the nut behind the valve handle, which wont budge, I don't think it's that kind of model. I've also tried opening and closing a few times, in case of rust or debris build-up. I'm still getting 2-3 drops per day.

Any advice?

[image: Main valve]

Comment: If the leak is on the street side of the meter, you need to turn off the feed from the mains to do anything serious with it. That one I'd leave to a pro.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried securing the valve's nut, which wont budge

Which nut? There's a nut that holds the handle in place, and there's another nut behind the handle. If you've only tightened the nut that shows in the photo then remove that nut, remove the handle and then tighten the other nut just a little to see if that stops the leak.

Comment: The nut behind the handle. Although I wouldn't really call it a nut. It's exagonal in shape but seems to be part of the assembly